# remove line comments from string

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I am writing a text parser, that needs to be able to remove comments from lines. I am using a rather simple language wherein all comments are initiated by a # character, and it would be simple to remove everything after that, but I have to deal with the possibility that the # is inside of a string.

My question, therefore, is, given a string such as
`Value="String#1";"String#2"; # This is an array of "-delimited strings, "Like this"`
How best can I extract the substring
`Value="String#1";"String#2";` (note the trailing space)

Note that the comment may contain quotes, and also, the entire line may choose between " and ' deliminating, although it will be consistent over the entire line. This is known beforehand, if it is important. Quotes within the strings will be escaped by a \

Comment: Every single lexer generator on this planet comes with examples that show how to deal with comments. Have you tried to use one? Have you tried to separate the lexical analysis phase at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::string stripComment(std::string str) {
    bool escaped = false;
    bool inSingleQuote = false;
    bool inDoubleQuote = false;
    for(std::string::const_iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); it++) {
         if(escaped) {
             escaped = false;
         } else if(*it == '\\' && (inSingleQuote || inDoubleQuote)) {
             escaped = true;
         } else if(inSingleQuote) {
             if(*it == '\'') {
                 inSingleQuote = false;
             }
         } else if(inDoubleQuote) {
             if(*it == '"') {
                 inDoubleQuote = false;
             }
         } else if(*it == '\'') {
             inSingleQuote = true;
         } else if(*it == '"') {
             inDoubleQuote = true;
         } else if(*it == '#') {
             return std::string(str.begin(), it);
         }
    }
    return str;
}
```

EDIT: Or a more textbook FSM,

```
std::string stripComment(std::string str) {
    int states[5][4] = {
    //      \  '  "
        {0, 0, 1, 2,}
        {1, 3, 0, 1,},  //single quoted string
        {2, 4, 2, 0,},  //double quoted string
        {1, 1, 1, 1,},  //escape in single quoted string
        {2, 2, 2, 2,},  //escape in double quoted string
    };
    int state = 0;
    for(std::string::const_iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); it++) {
        switch(*it) {
            case '\\':
                state = states[state][1];
                break;
            case '\'':
                state = states[state][2];
                break;
            case '"':
                state = states[state][3];
                break;
            case '#':
                if(!state) {
                    return std::string(str.begin(), it);
                }
            default:
                state = states[state][0];
        }          
    }
    return str;
}
```

The `states` array defines the transitioning between states of the FSM.

The first index is the current state, `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`.

The second index corresponds to the character, `\`, `'`, `"`, or another character.

The array tells the next state, based on the current state and the character.

FYI, these assume that backslashes escape any character in a string. You at least need them to escape backslashes, so you can have have a string ending with backslash.

Comment: You aren't dealing with # inside quotes.

Comment: Slow down and get it right before posting.  I was about to downvote your answer.

Comment: And now you've got enough cases to justify making it a `switch` block.  Would be easier to read.

Comment: `&& !inSingleQuote && !inDoubleQuote` is redundant.

Comment: Also: since you wrote a FSM you can get rid of all the flags and use a single enum variable.

Comment: I'm going to have to look at this later, when I'm not tired and using a four-inch-wide phone screen, because it certainly looks like magic to me now. Can you give me a simple synopsis, especially of the second one?

Comment: I believe that the `states[2]` line should read `{2, 4, 2, 0,}`, or you'll be ending "-strings with a '. Otherwise, thank you, This is exactly what I was wanting.